# flush remaining bytes on a socket

Tags: sockets, tcp

I have read in many places that it is NOT possible to flush the remaining bytes from a receive call on any socket besides a Unix Domain Socket. I need a way to not read all of the incoming data on a TCP socket without closing the connection. server sends 200 bytes I read 20 then go on to send the next request then call receive then the remaining 180 wont be there... How could i go about doing this?
Easier to read:

```
//Server sends 200 bytes
recv(180)
send("request")
//receive whole new response without the remaining bytes from the last one.
```

Comment: I'm not aware you can do it on a Unix domain socket either, unless you can `seek()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do what you want is to `recv()` the 180 unwanted bytes into a buffer, and then ignore (i.e. do not use) the contents of that buffer.

TCP is a strictly FIFO streaming protocol and it doesn't have any explicit provision for dropping bytes from the stream.

Comment: would something like QUIC have the ability to do this?